# XSL substring-after last occurrence of string

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible in XSL to substring from the last occurrence of some string to the end?

For example, I have some string:

```
xxx/yyy/zzz/xxx/www
```

I want to get substring from the last occurrence of '/' to the end:

```
www
```

If I use substring-after("xxx/yyy/zzz/xxx/www", "/") I get:

```
yyy/zzz/xxx/www
```

It's not what I want. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tokenize('xxx/yyy/zzz/xxx/www', '/')[last()]`,